# How do I create a shell script that calls an R script?

Tags: r, shell

[image: Sample problem for practice (not for marks)]
sample problem for practice (not for makrks)

```
#sourcing function
source('~/R/R-intro/myFuncs.R')

#vector
x <-c(-10,-3,2,4,5,0.3,-0.1,2.1,3.2,-12.1,-1.2)

#reads argument on the command line
your_arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

if (your_arg == 0) {
    neg.mean <- neg.mean(x)
    cat("The mean of the negative values of the data is",neg.mean, "\n")
    } else if (your_arg == 1) {
        geom.pos.mean <- geom.pos.mean(x)
    cat("The geometric mean of the positive values of the data is",
                geom.pos.mean, "\n")
    } else
    cat("Error, incorrect command line argument")
```

This is my code so far and it seems to work I just dont know how to connect it to the shell

Comment: I don't know how your bash script is setup, but if you are using Rscript it has an arguments `--args` flag to pass arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When you write in file `evalMeans.sh`:

```
Rscript selectMean.R 0
Rscript selectMean.R 1
```

and in file `selectMean.R`:

```
#reads argument on the command line
your_arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

#vector
x <-c(-10,-3,2,4,5,0.3,-0.1,2.1,3.2,-12.1,-1.2)

if (your_arg == 0) {
  cat("The mean of the negative values of the data is", mean(x[x<0]), "\n")
} else if (your_arg == 1) {
  cat("The geometric mean of the positive values of the data is",
      exp(mean(log(x[x>0]))), "\n")
} else
  cat("Error, incorrect command line argument")
```

You can type on the `shell`:

```
source evalMeans.sh
```

and it returns:

```
The mean of the negative values of the data is -5.28 
The geometric mean of the positive values of the data is 2.07854
```

In case you don't have `Rscript` write in file `evalMeans.sh`:

```
R --no-save -s < selectMean.R --args 0
R --no-save -s < selectMean.R --args 1
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your help! When I try to source 'evalMeans.sh' it gives me this error:$ source evalMeans.sh
bash: Rscript: command not found
bash: Rscript: command not found

Comment: I believe I am in the correct directory though and did save the file with the correct name

Comment: Maybe there is not `Rscript`. See updated Answer and try if `whereis Rscript` in `sh` finds it.